# Simple Error(While Loop) Help In my Java Palindrome Program

Tags: java, palindrome

I am building a palindrome program in Java. The assignment is to read the words from a file, determine if the words in the file are a palindrome or not, and send the result to another file. I have everything working but the only problem in my program is that it will only read the first word. I need it to read all of the lines in the file. My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class str1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {

      String reverse = "";
      System.out.print("Enter the name of the input file: ");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      String a = keyboard.nextLine();
      int length = a.length();
      File inFile = new File(a);
      Scanner fin = new Scanner(inFile);
      System.out.print("Enter name of the output file: ");
      String outFileName= keyboard.nextLine();
      File outFile = new File(outFileName);
      PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(outFile);
      while ( fin.hasNext(a) ) {
      for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
     reverse = reverse + a.charAt(i);

  if (a.equals(reverse))
     fout.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
  else
     fout.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");
      }
      fin.close();
      fout.close();
      System.out.print("Done. See '" + outFileName + "'.");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the while in line 23 to "while ( fin.hasNextLine(a) ) {" but I have no success. I believe this is why it wont read past the first line. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you checking for palindrome lines or just words?

Comment: Only checking lines with strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You need to add `nextLine` method after checking while condition for an input file, to actually process it, and also check the length of the word after reading it:

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Str1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            String reverse = "";
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the input file: ");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String a = keyboard.nextLine();
            File inFile = new File(a);
            Scanner fin = new Scanner(inFile);
            System.out.print("Enter name of the output file: ");
            String outFileName = keyboard.nextLine();
            File outFile = new File(outFileName);
            PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(outFile);
            while (fin.hasNext()) {
                String temp = fin.nextLine();
                int length = temp.length();
                for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    reverse = reverse + a.charAt(i);

                if (a.equals(reverse))
                    fout.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
                else
                    fout.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");
            }
            keyboard.close();
            fin.close();
            fout.close();
            System.out.print("Done. See '" + outFileName + "'.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! That makes sense to create a new string and set it to inFile.nextLine();

Comment: it should be fin, not inFile, my mistake.

Comment: thank you again for the helpful response. That seems to have made it all work great. Now Im pretty sure I need to tweak my if statement because it always produces a else response even for a palindrome.

Comment: No problem :) you can check the answer if you find it correct :)

Answer (score 0):

@QQ_At_The_PewPew, you are making a mistake, you are applying reverse on String "a" which is your filename, not your input from file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class str1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {

      String reverse = "";
      System.out.print("Enter the name of the input file: ");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      String a = keyboard.nextLine();
      int length = a.length();
      File inFile = new File(a);
      Scanner fin = new Scanner(inFile);
      System.out.print("Enter name of the output file: ");
      String outFileName= keyboard.nextLine();
      File outFile = new File(outFileName);
      PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(outFile);
      while ( fin.hasNext() ) {
      String s=fin.nextLine();
      for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
     reverse = reverse + s.charAt(i);

  if (s.equals(reverse))
     fout.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
  else
     fout.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");
      }
      fin.close();
      fout.close();
      System.out.print("Done. See '" + outFileName + "'.");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good eye. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I did. My rep isnʻt 15 yet since I just joined.